# Using Entity API, if given an entity in a function scope, how do you get the entity type?

Tags: 7, entities

This is very similar to this question: [How do I get entity_type and entity_id from any entity page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27747/how-do-i-get-entity-type-and-entity-id-from-any-entity-page)
But I don't know what that asker means by "Entity Page," and in my case, using `debug_backtrace` (seriously?) doesn't cut it as I'd like this function to actually work from more than 1 scope.

Anyway... I am writing a module that uses numerous Entity Reference fields, and works the same code over several types of entities.  The trouble is that in my function scope I don't know the type of entity.

If I pass an Entity object into a function, I can access its type parameter:

```
function foo ($entity) {
  // bundle is:
  $entity->type;
}
```

But how do I get the "Entity Type" from this object?

For example, I have a `dateset` entity type with several bundles: `class` and `retreat`.  When I pass an instance of the `class` bundle into my function, I can identify that it's a `class`, and use `identifier()` to get its ID.  But I want my function `foo()` to also handle `node` entity types with bundles `content_type_a` and `content_type_b`

Given any instance of one of those bundles, `foo()` can identify the bundle:

```
function foo ($entity) {
  $entity->type; // class, retreat, content_type_a or content_type_b
  $entity->indentifier(); // numeric ID
}
```

But what about getting `node` vs. `dateset`?  Doesn't `$entity` know what type of entity it is?

**UPDATE:**
Even though I accepted Yury's answer because it provided a realistic workaround, I think the true answer is that you cannot do this in Drupal.  You have to pass around $entity_type anywhere you pass $entity (which really kind of makes the idea of having Entities as objects pretty much worthless... but I think any Drupal developer knows that object oriented concepts in Drupal are just hacked in and not ever truly related to real world object oriented design).  See this Drupal issue: http://drupal.org/node/1042822

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various (convoluted) methods for getting the entity type and bundle, but none that I'd consider "acceptable" on a large-scale. What I've done is implemented `hook_entity_load()` and added the `entity_id` and `entity_type` properties on all entities at load-time.

The following code does this, and is part of the [Devtools](http://drupal.org/project/devtools) module I maintain:

```
function hook_entity_load($entities, $type) {
  // add the entity type & id to all entity objects for easy data access
  // from other hooks & modules
  foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    // we don't want to add these entity fields when the entity is being exported into
    // a feature, otherwise the feature will always show as overridden and will not 
    // revert
    if (  preg_match('#admin/structure/features#', $_GET['q'])  // features page
            || 
          (                                                     // drush fu command
            isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 
            preg_match('/drush\.php$/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) &&
            isset($_SERVER['argv'][2]) &&
            $_SERVER['argv'][2] == 'fu'
          )
       ) {
      continue;
    }

    // set entity_type
      $entity_type_field = (!isset($entity->entity_type)) ? 'entity_type' : 'devtools_entity_type';
      $entity->{$entity_type_field} = $type;

    // set entity_id
      $entity_id_field = (!isset($entity->entity_id)) ? 'entity_id' : 'devtools_entity_id';
      list($entity->{$entity_id_field}, $vid, $bundle) = entity_extract_ids($type, $entity);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: just reviewed the above code and it would make much more sense to have that `if()` statement outside the loop, and returning the function call.