# Rules Custom Condition for registration capacity

Tags: rules, database

I am trying to learn Rules and adding a custom condition. I need help to figure out what I am doing wrong.

My Condiiton set up:

```
function rules_example_capacity_condition_info() {
   $conditions = array(
     'rules_example_action_count_capacity' => array(
       'label' => t('Print capacity count on page'),
       'group' => t('Rules examples'),
       'parameters' => array(
         'count' => array('type' => 'value', 'label' => t('registration event count')),
         'capacity' => array('type' => 'value', 'label' => t('registration event capacity')),         
         ),
       ),
     );
     return $conditions; 
 }
```

and the function that calls it...

```
function rules_example_action_count_capacity($count, $capacity) {
    $reg_count = reg_count_load($count);
    return($reg_count->capacity == $capacity) ? true : false;
}
```

I am trying to determine the count (how many people have registered so far) and the capacity. When the count and capacity are the same send an email.

I am not a developer so this is a little bit of a struggle. I found this series (http://nodeone.se/node/28) which is helpful, however there are so many smaller things I might be missing. Please help if you can. I am hoping that this will help more then just myself.

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your function, I believe you need to rename it to something like mymodule_rules_condition_info. The hook you are trying to implement is `hook_rules_condition_info()`. Did you find that your custom condition was showing up when you were editing a rule?

```
function MYMODULE_rules_condition_info() {
   $conditions = array(
     'mymodule_event_is_at_capacity' => array(
       'label' => t('Event has reached maximum registrations'),
       'group' => t('MY MODULE'),
       'parameters' => array(
         'registration' => array(
            'type' => 'registration',
            'label' => t('The registration event'),
           ),         
         ),
       ),
     );
     return $conditions; 
 }
```

Semantically you may want to call your condition 'mymodule_event_is_at_capacity' and it should only need one parameter which is the capacity that you will provide in the Rules UI.

The function you will be writing `mymodule_event_is_at_capacity($capacity)` will query for the number of (active) users in Drupal, and if it is greater than or equal to $capacity, it will return TRUE.

All of this can be kicked off by add a new Rule that reacts on the "After saving a new user account" event.

Comment: Thanks for the information! However, I am still a little confused. While the tweaked you shared does help a little, I still need to set up a function for the action. Right now the above triggers whenever you go to a page with Registration on it, not when capacity is hit. My guess is the function to call the action would control that. I think that I have to compare the registration count with the capacity to trigger the email.

I do have a rule set up 'After saving a new registration'. I was hoping that this new condition could help count the registrations and and compare to the capacity.

Comment: Yes. You should look at the code for the registration modules. It has two functions, `registration_has_room()` and `registration_event_count()` which should help you. Your callback for your condition should only need to take in one parameter, which is the $registration that was just saved and it should be able to return TRUE/FALSE by passing that $registration to the `registration_has_room()` function. If it returns TRUE, your action for your Rule will send the email.

Comment: Okay, that all makes sense, however I do not know how to write the function that passes `$registration` to `registration_has_room()` and return true or false. I have search but cannot find anything that helps me. I have tried multiple ideas. Hoping that there is a an example somewhere...If you know or can share please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to take so long. This did answer my question. I tend to have questions on my questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Al Gorgeous Thank you for you help. Below is the final working example.

So, I had a lot to learn here. I have some help figuring this out.

I had to create a custom condition for Rules and then figure out the true/false statement to trigger the email. The hard part was having to figure out how to bring in the entity_id. I found this hacked way and it worked.

Hacked way to to grab the entity_id - [How do I get entity_type and entity_id from any entity page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27747/how-do-i-get-entity-type-and-entity-id-from-any-entity-page)

```
function ecg_registration_rules_condition_info() {
  $conditions = array(
  'ecg_registration_event_is_at_capacity' => array(
       'label' => t('Event has reached maximum registrations'),
       'group' => t('MY MODULE'),
       'parameters' => array(
         'registration' => array(
            'type' => 'registration',
            'label' => t('The registration event capacity'),
           ),   
         ),
       ),
}
```

The function that tracks and triggers the capacity count.

```
function ecg_registration_event_is_at_capacity($registration) {
  $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
  foreach ($backtrace as $caller) {
    if ($caller['function'] == 'field_attach_view') {
      $entity_type = $caller['args'][0];
      $entity = $caller['args'][1];
      // do stuff with entity
      break;
    }  
  } 
  $entity_id = $entity->{'nid'};  
  $count =  registration_event_count($entity_type, $entity_id);
  $settings = registration_entity_settings($entity_type, $entity_id);
  if ($settings['capacity'] == 0) {
    return FALSE;
    break;
  } 
  if ($count >= $settings['capacity']) {   
      return TRUE;
  } 
  return FALSE;
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.